# Mongoose validation error on POST request

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to do a POST request using express on node.js and mongoose for mongoDB but using Postman to get data gives me this error:

> Error
>     at MongooseError.ValidationError
>   (C:\Users\Matteo\Desktop\app1\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\validation.js:22:16)
>      at model.Document.invalidate
>   (C:\Users\Matteo\Desktop\app1\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1162:32)
>      at
>   C:\Users\Matteo\Desktop\app1\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1037:16
>      at validate
>   (C:\Users\Matteo\Desktop\app1\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:651:7)
>      at
>   C:\Users\Matteo\Desktop\app1\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:679:9
>      at Array.forEach (native)
>     at
>   SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate
>   (C:\Users\Matteo\Desktop\app1\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:656:19)
>      at
>   C:\Users\Matteo\Desktop\app1\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1035:9
>      at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)

I paste here my server.js file

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json())

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/social', function(){
    console.log('mongodb connected')
})

var postSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    username : { type: String, required: true },
    body : { type: String, required: true },
    date : { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now}
})
var Post = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema)

app.get('/api/posts', function(req, res, next){
    Post.find(function(err, posts){
        if(err) { return next(err) }
        res.json(posts)
    })
})

app.post('/api/posts', function(req, res, next){
    var post = new Post({
        username : req.body.username,
        body : req.body.body
    })
    post.save(function(err, post){
        if(err){ return next(err) }
        res.json(201, post)
    })
})

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Server listening on', 3000)
})
```

Can anyone help me or it is a problem of mongoose?

Comment: Is `req.body` an actual object with `username` and `body`? I see that you're missing inclusion of `bodyParser` middleware, as in: `app.use(bodyParser.json());` line,.

Comment: What does `console.log(req.body)` print to the console?

Comment: @royhowie just these two brackets {}

Comment: What about if you add this line: `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))`

Comment: @royhowie nothing, gives me the same error, everything works fine if i do a GET request

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar error today, and reading the docs helped me through.

The doc says:

> Defining validators on nested objects in mongoose is tricky, because nested objects are not fully fledged paths.

```
var personSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    first: String,
    last: String
  }
});
```

A schema like the above will throw similar error like in your question.

The docs points out the workaround:

```
var nameSchema = new Schema({
  first: String,
  last: String
});

personSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: nameSchema,
    required: true
  }
});
```

Source: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html

Answer (score 1):

in Postman, to test HTTP post actions with raw JSON data, need to select the raw option and also set the header parameters( select header parameter in postman and add in *key:value* feild which is given below ).

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

by default, it comes with  `Content-Type: text/plain` which need to replace with `Content-Type: application/json`

Answer (score 0):

I think it's Mongoose Validation issue, req.body is actually a JSON formatted-data, console.log(req.body.username) returns the username value. To be general, try to use req.body, please make use to fill-out the required fields upon submission.

```
app.post('/api/posts', function(req, res, next){
var post = new Post(req.body);
post.save(function(err, post){
    if(err){ return next(err) }
    res.json(post)
})
})
```

Better to handle MongooseError.ValidationError when a user fails to fill-in required fields. Try to review your Mongoose Model.